# How to share custom getter and setter methods across models in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have these custom getter and setter methods in some of my models:

```
def hourly_rate
  hourly_rate_in_cents.to_d / 100 if hourly_rate_in_cents
end

def hourly_rate=(number)
  self.hourly_rate_in_cents = number.to_d * 100 if number.present?
end
```

Is it possible to share these across models?

If so where would I put them and how would I include them in the models that need them?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pull them out into a separate module, which can be defined in a module directory, e.g. `app/modules`

Then just include them in you model, e.g. `include 'hourly_rate'`

Comment: OK, that works and was surprisingly easy. Thanks! Even though I put the module in the `lib` folder. Hope that's not breaking any conventions?

Comment: You can put it wherever you like!  My personal preference is to put custom classes and modules in app/classes and app/modules, but there's not a hard rule I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (not the best but it depends on your situation) way is to add them into your

```
apps/controllers/application_controller.rb
```

file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a module. Some links:

[mixin](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/) & [modules](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm)